# iOS Missing Push notification Entitlement warning

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

In our app we don't use push notification, we did not enable the push notification in identifier. we create the distribution profile with disable push notification and submit on app store. but we got text(check below) in mail.

-> What is the reason for getting this kind of mail?
-> Is there any issue in distribution profile?

give me solution.

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

There are few third parties framework like airpush or urbanairship etc that register your app for pushnotification with out even declaring it on appdelegate or without even using any server to send notification.
So make sure whatever framework you are using it must not be using any of the pushnotification process.