# Missing Push Notification Entitlement?

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode6, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

> NOTE: I have read other stackoverflow questions relating to this topic
> but they did not help me. I also do not use any third-party SDKs.

When I submitted my app to the App Store, this is the message that I received after a few hours:

*I only uploaded the App and enabled Test-Flight, I did not submit it for App-Review.

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "APP NAME". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
> API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
> app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
> Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
> not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
> You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
> If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
> developer for information on removing the API.

I do NOT have any push notification services or anything and this came up. I have NOT set up ANY Notification Services on my App Provisioning Profile. I checked my App Capabilities in XCode and do NOT have Background-Modes Enabled.  Earlier versions of the app have successfully passed through. They have NOT been using the Push-Notifications services. I have checked out other similar stackoverflow questions relating to this topic but they did not help me. Do you know a solution that can help me solve this problem?

---

UPDATE 2:

I resubmitted by app. Same mail was sent to me.

Comment: do you include a third party library? like pusher, flurry, parse ....

Comment: Edit your app identifier in the developer.apple.com portal and select the APNS entitlement. After that, create a new provisioning profile.

Comment: @tomsoft As I said above, I do not use any third-party things

Comment: @ZeMoon ill try that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to do what it says:

> If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no
>   action is required.

It seems fairly clear by unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research it is a bug from Apple. You should just ignore this as everything will work fine. 
Ref:

[Missing Push Notification Entitlement Warning in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311097/missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning-in-email/32311431#32311431)
and 
[iOS Missing Push notification Entitlement warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350618/ios-missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning/32351341#32351341)

Comment: This was also the conclusion I reached when I had the same issue.

Comment: @algal ok I am re-uploading the App

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same issues and everyone (included the client) was already really annoyed by those emails.

In our case an ancient dependency (FirebaseMessaging) has seemed to register to didReceiveRemoteNotification in some swizzling code - this triggered those warning-emails even if the app itself has no incorrect or mismatching settings.

Once the library is gone everything works fine again...